# azure powershell commandlets for vms metrics like cpu utilization ,network in , network out

Tags: azure, metrics

Are there ant powershel commands to get to know about the vms metric like cpu utilized in percentage , network in and network out.So that I can use these commands in my  c# code to display performance graphs for these vms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if API for metrics even exists.
But the good news here is if you have Diagnosticts setup as it is described here http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/performance-profiling/ you will have performance counters information stored in your WADPerformanceCountersTable table.